# Using the OAuth2.0 Token.Credentials for acessing GData

Tags: c#, google-api, google-apps, google-api-dotnet-client

I need some help - I'm still in the process of wrapping my head around the NEW Google Admin SDK using the Directory API.  So far I'm able to create/delete a user, create/delete an Alias.  I've authorized the scopes in those areas I need to etc.

My Question is how to I use the existing code below in order to use the GData Libraries?  I need to use the "CreateSendAs()" function but that uses another set of includes that are different from the Directory API.  Do I have to set an Auth2.0 token to something so that I can use the older GData calls?

**I use for the Directory API:**

```
    const string serviceAccountEmail = "XXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

    const string serviceAccountCertPath = @"C:\XX-privatekey.p12";
    const string serviceAccountCertPassword = "notasecret";
    const string userEmail = "super-admin-user@domain.com";

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(serviceAccountCertPath, serviceAccountCertPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
{
Scopes = new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser },
User = userEmail
}.FromCertificate(certificate));
var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
HttpClientInitializer = credential,
ApplicationName = APP_NAME,
});
```

**This the C# code I need to use for the "CreateSendAs()" function.**

```
using Google.GData.Apps;
using Google.GData.Apps.GoogleMailSettings;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;

GoogleMailSettingsService service = new GoogleMailSettingsService("yourdomain", "your-apps");

service.setUserCredentials("adminUsername", "adminPassword");
service.CreateSendAs("liz", "Sales", "sales@example.com", "", "true");
```

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi there, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Ive solved it as this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31069464/1390235

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much correct the following approach is but that is what worked for me. Using the service credentials token you can access the GoogleMailSettingsService as follows

```
bool success =  credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;

OAuth2Parameters parameter = new OAuth2Parameters()
{
     AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken
};

GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory("apps","your-apps", parameter);
GoogleMailSettingsService service = new GoogleMailSettingsService("yourdomain", "your-apps");
service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
service.CreateSendAs("liz", "Sales", "sales@example.com", "", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work.  I'm able to set the AccessToken from the credential but not I'm getting the following error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: refresh_token